# Aggregate function COUNT not scalar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The COUNT function doesn't result in a scalar as expected:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (Col1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 INT)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(2,3,9) -- Row 1
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(1,5,7) -- Row 2
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(2,3,9) -- Row 3
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(3,4,9) -- Row 4

SELECT COUNT(*) AS Result
FROM MyTable
WHERE Col3=9
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
```

I filter out the 3 rows where Col3=9.

In the remaining 3 rows there are two groups:

Group 1 where Col1=2 AND Col2=3 (Row 1 and 3)

Group 2 where Col1=3 AND Col2=4 (Row 4)

Finally I count those two rows.

Therefore, I expect the answer to be a scalar Result = 2 (the two groups where Col3=9).

But I got a non scalar result.

There are other ways to solve the this, so thats not the problem, but where am I thinking wrong?

Comment: You're grouping on Columns `Col1` and `Col2`, so you'll get 1 row per distinct set of those columns. If you want a single scalar value, then you don't want a `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for the total count of all the groups matching any condition. For this try like the following query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) [Count] FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Result
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Col3=9
    GROUP BY Col1, Col2
)T
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7a501b/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery with singe aggregation :

```
select count(*)
from (select distinct col1, col2
      from mytable
      where col3 = 9
     ) t;
```